# Windows 7 Library Location Limit

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, windows-libraries

In Windows 7, many folders can be added to a library and, in many ways, act as one folder.

Is there a limit to the number of Library locations within a library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Is there a limit to the number of Library locations within a library?

You can have as many **subfolders** as you want, but there is a limit of 50 **parent** folders.

> Q: On page 79 of [Windows 7 For Dummies](http://www.andyrathbone.com/books/windows-7-for-dummies/), you say you can add “as many
> folders to a library as you want.”
>
> But [Windows 7’s Help and Support files Libraries FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Libraries-frequently-asked-questions) says you can only
> add “up to 50 folders.” Which is it?
>
> A: **The answer is a little tricky. Yes, you can add as many folders to
> a library as you want.**
>
> For example, you can dump hundreds of album folders into your Music
> Library’s My Music folder. You can dump hundreds of album folders into
> the Music Library’s Public Music folder, as well.
>
> However, a library can only have 50 parent folders. What’s a parent
> folder? It’s a top-level folder. For example, the Music Library
> currently has two parent folders: The My Music folder and Public Music
> folder are top-level folders, or parents. That leaves room for 48 more
> parent folders.
>
> So, if you store all of your music in either your library’s My Music
> or Public Music folders, you’ll never bump into the Music library’s
> 50-folder limit. You can even add up to 48 other parent folders,
> adding a “Music I Hate” folder to live next to the My Music and Public
> Music folders.
>
> But you’re best served by storing all of your music in either your My
> Music or Public Music folders, as that makes for the simplest sharing
> on your home network.

Source [What’s this "50 Folder” limit to Windows 7’s libraries?](http://www.andyrathbone.com/2009/11/16/whats-this-50-folder-limit-to-windows-7s-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

50 locations inside a library is the limit.

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/libraries-faq#1TC=windows-7

It is listed under the "How do I create or change a library" heading.